# need to bind the current sitecollection name in lookup field and pass the corresponding lookupid in onstart of canvas app new form

Tags: reactjs, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I create a new form using canvas app. i had a lookup field name companies.
I need to bind the lookup field dropdown with current sitecollection name from the following options in new form of canvas app

Comment: Please help me to solve this

Comment: did you looked into [this article](https://wonderlaura.com/2017/08/16/powerapps-set-sharepoint-lookup-field/) Also could you share your query/connection. I mean how are you fetching your data from sharepoint.